# How to solve this finite difference equation related to falling factorials?

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I am following [Gleich(2005): "Finite Calculus: A Tutorial for Solving Nasty Sums"](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf). At one point when referring to the fact that

> The function $H_x$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) is
>   the antiderivative of $x^{\underline{-1}}$ (The underline is a notation to write a falling factorial, $x^{\underline{-1}} = \dfrac{1}{x+1}$).

The author writes

> There is no easy way of getting the correct function ($H_x$) intuitively.

So I am wondering what is the way of getting the correct function? I realized that basically one has to solve the following finite difference equation for $f(x)$:
$$
f(x+1) - f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}.
$$
But, apart from guessing the correct function, is there a systematic way of solving such an equation to see that the solution is $f(x) = H_x$?

Update: This finite difference equation is of course the discrete version of
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x+h}
$$ 
or short $\frac{df}{dx} = 1/x$ with the solution $f(x) = \ln(x) + C$.

Comment: Please provide some context: What does it mean here to "get the correct function"? (Answers should be self-contained and not completely rely on external sources.)

Comment: Isn't this just telescoping?…

Comment: @flawr "get the correct function" means solving the shown finite difference equation to get the correct function $H_x$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm searching for an systematic way of solving such a finite difference equation. Just inserting $H_x$ into the finite difference equation to prove that this is the correct solution, is not what I want.

Comment: @asmaier What exactly is the domain of $f$? Is it $\mathbb{N}$ or $[0,+∞)$?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) which is a solution.

Comment: @Somos the digamma function fulfills $f(x+1) - f(x) = 1/x$ but the equation here is $f(x+1) -f(x) = 1/(x+1)$ . This is close, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

By [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series),$$
f(n) = f(0) + \sum_{k = 1}^n (f(k) - f(k - 1)) = f(0) + \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k} = f(0) + H_n.
$$

Comment: And what about the arbitrary x?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov I wonder how harmonic numbers are defined for arbitrary $x$.

Comment: I can't follow your steps. How do you come up with the sum?

Comment: @asmaier The difference equation is $f(k+1)-f(k)=\dfrac1{k+1}$, no?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the solution is determined up to an arbitrary periodic summand function $P_1(x)$ with period $1.$

Then, applying Laplace transformation 
$$\mathcal L(f(x)) = F(s)$$
to the issue equation in the form of
$$f(x)-f(x-1) = \dfrac1x,$$
one can get
$$F(s) = \dfrac1{1-e^{-s}} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty e^{-ns},$$
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{u(x-n)}{x-n}+P_1(x),\quad x \ge 1,$$
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{u(x-n)}{x-n}+P_1(x),$$
where
$$u(x) =\begin{cases}
0,\text{ if } x<0\\
1,\text{ if } x\ge0.\\
\end{cases}$$

---

**Addition of 12.06.18**

Let us consider the case of the integer positive $x$ with the initial condition
$$f(1) = 1.$$
Then
$$P_1(x) = C + Z_1(x),$$
where $C$ is the constant, which can be defined from the initial conditions, and
$Z_1(x)$ is the arbitrary periodic function, which satisfy the condition $Z_1(1)= 0.$

For example, $Z_1(x)$ can be choosen in the form of
$$Z_1(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} A_i\sin2\pi ix,$$
where $A_i$ are the arbitrary coefficients.

So
$$f(1) = 1 + C + Z_1(1),$$
$$1 = 1 + C,$$
$$ C= 0,$$
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{u(x-n)}{x-n} + Z_1(x),\quad x\ge1,$$
$$f(m) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \dfrac1k,\quad m\in\mathbb N.$$

Comment: How does this work for $x=1$? Is $f(1+1)-f(1) = 1/2$? I get $f(1) = 3/2 +P_1(0)$ and $f(2) = 5/4 + P_1(0)$ implies $f(2)-f(1) = -1/4.$

Comment: @Somos Thank you for the comment. See addition.

Comment: I get $f(1) = 1+Z_1(0)$ and $f(2)=5/4 + Z_1(0)$ implies $f(2)-f(1)=1/4.$

Comment: @Somos You are right, the Heavyside function should not be applied for 1D transform. Thank you, fixed.

Comment: I am sorry, but it should be $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{x-n} u(x-n) + Z_1(x)$

Comment: @Somos I've checked, you're right. Thank you for support.